# Combining 2 columns in the same pandas dataframe into a new column, keeping only specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am working through a dataset that has information on used cars, and the dataset was missing some of the Year values. My idea was to try and use some of the VIN numbers to decode the year, and fill in any missing years into a new column. My goal is to create a new column which has the original Years that were there, as well as any of the missing year values that I was able to decode from the VIN number. Here is a sample:

```
Original Dataframe:
    year    vin_year
0   2009    ***
1   2010    ***
2   ***     2010
3   2020    2020
4   ***     2011
5   ***     ***

Updated Dataframe:
    year    vin_year    all_year
0   2009    ***         2009
1   2010    ***         2010
2   ***     2010        2010
3   2020    2020        2020
4   ***     2011        2011
5   ***     ***         ***
```

The code I have tried so far is below, however I am getting 'invalid syntax'. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

```
for i in vehicle_data['year']:
    for j in vehicle_data['vin_year']:
        if i != j and j != '***':
            vehicle_data['all_year'] = j
            else vehicle_data['allyear'] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy where is a great solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make an example
data = {'A' : [2000, '***',2010, '***'], 'B' : [2000, 2005, 2010, '***']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# combine the results
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == '***', df['B'], df['A'])

df
```